# How to start mongodb from dockerfile

Tags: mongodb, docker

I'm building a dockerfile. But I meet a problem. It says that :

> /bin/sh: 1: mongod: not found

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mongo:latest
FROM node

RUN mongod

COPY . .
RUN node ./scripts/import-data.js
```

Here is what happen when docker build:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  829.5MB
Step 1/8 : FROM rabbitmq
 ---> e8261c2af9fe
Step 2/8 : FROM portainer/portainer
 ---> 00ead811e8ae
Step 3/8 : FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.5.1
 ---> 32f93c89076d
Step 4/8 : FROM mongo:latest
 ---> 5976dac61f4f
Step 5/8 : FROM node
 ---> b074182f4154
Step 6/8 : RUN mongod
 ---> Running in 0a4b66a77178
/bin/sh: 1: mongod: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c mongod' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Looks more like you should be using docker-compose defining all your services that interact with each other rather than attempting to bake all the services in a single image. Images are intended to be lightweight and most often only run a single process (not multiple processes, not that it’s impossible but you’ll need i.e. supervisord or something of the likes to manage all those processes).

Comment: Yes, but we hoped to have one image to rule the all (sorry, i had to make this joke). But yes, will try by docker compose so.... Many thanks again !

Comment: Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56689522/1423507), you don't have 1 image to rule them all but 1 config file to do it (ideally checked into some VCS). Ref. your comments "Docker is not that useful as hoped*" - the beauty of `docker` (imho) is that in ~45 minutes I was able to deploy: `mongo`, `node`, `rabbitmq`, `portainer` and `elasticsearch` - one of which I've never touched before. More time to focus on building my app(s) than the environment in which my app(s) need to run, leave that to the image maintainers.

Comment: Yes yes I understood, we just hoped it and we are thinking wrong way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are using two `FROM` instructions, which is referred to as a [`multi-stage build`](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). The final image will be based on the `node` image that doesn't contain the `mongo` database.

*** Edit ***

here are more details about what is happening:

> FROM mongo:latest

- the base image is `mongo:latest`

> FROM node

- now the base image is `node:latest`. The previous image is just standing there...

> RUN mongod
>
> COPY . .
>
> RUN node ./scripts/import-data.js

- now you run `mongod` and the other commands in your final image that is based on `node` (which doesn't contain mongo)

Comment: I hoped that nobody will answer that. Disapointed... Docker is not that useful as hopped. Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

It happens because multiple FROM instructions should be used for [Multistage Build (check the documentation)](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) and NOT for image creation contains all of present applications.

Multistage builds provide you possibility of delegation building process into container's environment without local application installation.

```sh
FROM rabbitmq

...some instructions require rabbitmq...

FROM mongo:latest

...some instructions require mongo...
```

In other words if you want to create an image with rabbitmq, mongo and other application you have to choose the image and install applications manually.

Comment: I hoped that nobody will answer that. Disapointed... Docker is not that useful as hopped. Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use `docker-compose` (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) to run the images rather than attempting to build a new image from a collection of existing images. Your `docker-compose.yml` might look something like:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  portainer:
    image: 'portainer/portainer'
    container_name: 'portainer'
    hostname: 'portainer'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    volumes:
    - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
    - 'portainer_data:/data'
    ports:
    - '9000:9000'
  rabbitmq:
    image: 'rabbitmq'
    container_name: 'rabbitmq'
    hostname: 'rabbitmq'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    volumes:
    - 'rabbitmq_data:/var/lib/rabbitmq'
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'elasticsearch:7.1.1'
    container_name: 'elasticsearch'
    hostname: 'elasticsearch'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    environment:
    - 'discovery.type=single-node'
    volumes:
    - 'elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data'
    ports:
    - '9200:9200'
    - '9300:9300'
  node:
    image: 'node:12'
    container_name: 'node'
    hostname: 'node'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    user: 'node'
    working_dir: '/home/node/app'
    environment:
    - 'NODE_ENV=production'
    volumes:
    - './my-app:/home/node/app'
    ports:
    - '3000:3000'
    command: 'npm start'
  mongo:
    image: 'mongo'
    container_name: 'mongo'
    hostname: 'mongo'
    domainname: 'example.com'
    restart: 'always'
    environment:
    - 'MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root'
    - 'MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example'
    volumes:
    - 'mongo_data:/data/db'
volumes:
  portainer_data:
  rabbitmq_data:
  elasticsearch_data:
  mongo_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

For some testing purpose, I actually had to cram both MongoDB and NodeJS in the same container.

I first tried to use the Alpine-based Node image

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.19
```

but figured out you could not import Mongo through `apk` commands as it's not available anymore on the latest Alpine.

I thus did it the other way around, starting from the Ubuntu-based Mongo image and using `apt-get` to import `node` and `npm` in the image

```
FROM mongo:7.0.7

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl && \
    curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score -1):

I see, quite simple

step1. create this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:latest
```

step2. create image from this Dockerfile:

```
docker build . -t my_mongo_build
```

This is equal to `docker run ..... mongo:latest`, used for some strange scenario