# Disable cache for from image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I'm writing a Dockerfile that depends on another image in a multistage build. Here is it

```
FROM my_another_image:latest as mai

...
```

The problem is I don't want to manually delete `my_another_image:latest` any time I'm building the image from the `Dockerfile` (I never know when the update for `my_another_image:latest` is available). Is there a way to disable cache for the `FROM` statement in the Dockerfile? `docker build --no-cache` preverents the image built from `Dockerfile` from caching, not its dependencies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but using [`docker build --pull`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options) will "always attempt to pull a newer version of the image". If you do pull a new `latest` tag the old image will just be untagged (e.g. `docker` will remove the tag from the previous image and tag the pulled image), it won't be deleted automatically (you'd need to i.e. `docker image prune -f` to remove untagged images). You can retag an old image version using the image id i.e. `docker tag 5f33a9df08a7 my_another_image:latest`.

Comment: @masseyb is it possible to specify which image to `pull`? I have lots of images that I dont want to pull which pretty large in size.

Comment: `docker build --pull` will only attempt to pull newer versions for the images specified in the `FROM` statements of the `Dockerfile` you're building, it won't attempt to pull anything outside of the build. Is basically the same as looking at each `FROM` image in the `Dockerfile` and trying to `docker pull` each one of those images before doing the build.

Comment: @masseyb Right, but I have multiple `FROM`s like `postgres` and `kafka`. I'd be nice to avoid pulling them. Is that possible?

Comment: If they are all in the same `Dockerfile` then no (I mean you could build to a specific `--target` stage but it will attempt to pull the `FROM` images up until the target stage if you're using multi-staged builds).

Comment: If you do have multiple `FROM`'s like that in a single `Dockerfile`, unless you have a real obligation to do so, I'd suggest splitting the `Dockerfile` up, build 1 image per service and [run your services using `docker-compose`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56689522/1423507) or in Kubernetes [for various reasons](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/451).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the purpose of "docker build --pull"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58488535/whats-the-purpose-of-docker-build-pull)